# Is the matrix element symmetric in a cross-section computation?

Tags: s-matrix-theory, scattering-cross-section, matrix-elements

Let's consider the cross-section of $A+B\rightarrow C+D$.
This involves the usage of an "matrix element" : $M$ for the amplitude of the reaction.

Is the element matrix of $A+B\rightarrow C+D$ the same as the one of $C+D\rightarrow A+B$ ?

If so, is the $cross-section$ of $A+B\rightarrow C+D$ the same as the one of $C+D\rightarrow A+B$ ?

If so, let's consider $A+B\rightarrow C+D$ : what does prevent that $C+D\rightarrow A+B$ immediatly after ?
If so, how would know whether the outgoing particles $A+B$ have occured a reaction (potentially an infinite number of reactions) or didn't occur any reaction ?

Comment: The matrix elements are the same, given the suitable momentum reversals of incoming and outgoing momenta. But the differing phase space factors in the respective Lorentz-invariant phase-space integrals are distinctly, aggressively different, as you learn in your QFT text.